# Why I can't access array element?

Tags: java, loops

I have a class named "Soldier" and also I have a class named "Army" containing an array of Soldier class objects. Army class is defined like this:

```
public class Army {
    Array<Soldier> army;
```

Then, in Army class constructor I'm creating Soldier objects array like this:

```
public Army(){
    army = new Array<Soldier>(20); // Here
}
```

So far I was iterating thru army array like this:

```
for (Soldier soldier : army) {
    // do something with soldier object
}
```

And that worked well, but when I wanted to do nested iteration that way (one loop inside another one) it all get messed up - inner loop was destroying outer loop iterator index.

So, I want to do "manual" iteration, with simple for loop and it looks like this:

```
for (int i=0; i< army.army.size; i++) {
    Soldier soldier = army.army.items[i];
```

But I'm getting run time error (exception):

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.mgsoft.Soldier;
```

Can someone please explain me what's going on here? Why I can't access my soldier objects that way and what's the proper way to access them?

Comment: We have no idea what Array is (it's not a standard class), we have no idea what army.army is (why does an army have an army?). So, in short, the posted code is not sufficient to help.

Comment: If in "for (Soldier soldier : army)" army is instanceof Army and not armyObject.army could you post your iterator implementation?

Comment: I explained that army object contains army array. So first army is Army class object and second is array inside that object.

And I thought that Array is Java stuff....it's part of LibGDX then, that I'm using. They are suggesting use of it.

I'm not very experienced with Java, but I tried to explain my problem best I could. Why down voting?

Comment: So, probably not best naming solution, but first army is object of class Army and second one is that array of Soldier class objects, part of Army class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In manual way :

```
for (int i=0; i< army.size(); i++) {
  Soldier soldier = army.get(i);
```

If you get data from `ArrayList` then you can get data directly  by `get` method. For get the size of `ArrayList` use `listName.size()`

Comment: It's actually army.army.get(i); but point is correct. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Array use ArrayList like:

```
  ArrayList<Soldier> army;
```

And you'll have:

```
 for (int i=0; i< army.size; i++) {
  Soldier soldier = army.get(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to implement `Iterable`:

```
public class Army implements Iterable<Soldier> {
    private final List<Soldier> soldiers;

    public Army(List<Soldier> soldiers) {
        this.soldiers = soldiers;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Soldier> iterator() {
        return soldiers.iterator();
    }
}
```

Then you can simply write

```
for(Soldier s : army) {
     for(Soldier t : army) {
         System.out.println(s + "  " + t);
     }
 }
```

The loops won't interfere, as you get always a new iterator from the internal list of soldiers. I don't know how exactly your `Array` type works, but if it is an `Iterable` as well, you can use it exactly the same way I used lists.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
for (int i=0; i< army.army.size; i++) {
    Soldier s = army.army.items[i];
}
```

Your implementation should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < army.size(); i++){
    Soldier soldier = army.get(i);
}
```

The reason behind, "**army.army**" doesn't exist, hence it's size is irrelevant.

Also, in the line:

```
Soldier s = army.army.items[i];
```

the "army.army" part is invalid.

When you are trying to access the first "Soldier" element in the array, the best way is to use

```
arrayName.get(index);
```

method. The "get(element at index i) method is a method of the Array class.

Comment: Also, as mentioned by @Abdelhak, please replace your Array with ArrayList

Comment: What are benefits with replacing array with array list? If I do that do I have to change something else?